# passing structure reference from a c# code to call a c++ DLL function that accept structure reference in its prototype

Tags: c#, c++, dll, reference, parameter-passing

I hav a function in c++ DLL that has following prototype

`int function(RefPar &params);`

how can i call this function from a c# program using "DLLImport".

when i tried like below, `AccessViolationException` happened while running in visual studio 2008..

```
[DllImport("VistaGMMDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "function"]
unsafe static extern int function(ref RefPar params);
```

and called as..

```
int ret=function(ref params);
```

> **Note**:RefPar structure has many
>   unsigned integer values and 1 enum
>   value as its members.

pls anyone help me to call the function correctly..

Comment: I have very little experience with marshalling to native code, but you may need to pass it as an `IntPtr`.  You also are going to have to be very careful with how you define your structure in both C# and C++, since the structure layout/packing is completely different between the languages.

Comment: I am using [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] for layout packing.

Comment: I think you may need to use some special keywords in C++ also to ensure (portably) a specific object layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RefPar
{
    UInt32 uint1;
    UInt32 unti2;
    ....
} 


[DllImport("VistaGMMDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "function"]
unsafe static extern int function(IntPtr params);

//calling

//fill the refParStructure
//create the IntPtr  

refParStruct rs = new RefPar();

IntPtr refparPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(refPar)));


Marshal.StructureToPtr(refParStruct, refparPtr,false);
ret=function(refParPtr);
```

Let Me know if you need more details

Comment: Hi.. thanks for the reply.. I am new to c#.. i Did wat u said.Created an IntPtr in this way.                           IntPtr refptr=new IntPtr();                      Marshal.StructureToPtr(refparstruct,refptr, true);                ArgumentNullException is coming for refptr, pls tell do i have to initialize IntPtr differently??

Comment: Hello, you have to allocate the pointer using refptr=Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(size));

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things jump out at me.  First of all I don't see why you need to use unsafe.  Secondly, you probably have a calling convention mismatch, cdecl in the C++ and stdcall in the C#.

I'd do it like this:

**C++**

```
struct RESOURCE_PARAMETERS{
    unsigned int uSurfaceHeight;
    unsigned int uSurfaceDepth;
    unsigned int uSurfaceWidth;
    unsigned int uMSAAHeight;
    unsigned int uMSAAWidth;
    unsigned int uArraySize;
    unsigned int uNumSamples;
    unsigned int uMaxLod;
    unsigned int uBpp;
    unsigned int uprefFlag;
    unsigned int uusageFlag;
    RESOURCE_TYPE_REC ResourceType;
    int ResourceFormat;
    int iBuildNumber;
};

int function(RefPar &parameters)
{
}
```

**C#**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RESOURCE_PARAMETERS
{
    uint uSurfaceHeight;
    uint uSurfaceDepth;
    uint uSurfaceWidth;
    uint uMSAAHeight;
    uint uMSAAWidth;
    uint uArraySize;
    uint uNumSamples;
    uint uMaxLod;
    uint uBpp;
    uint uprefFlag;
    uint uusageFlag;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    ResourceType ResourceType;
    int ResourceFormat;
    int iBuildNumber;
} 

[DllImport("VistaGMMDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int function(ref RESOURCE_PARAMETERS parameters);

RESOURCE_PARAMETERS parameters = new RESOURCE_PARAMETERS();
int result = function(ref parameters);
```

I'm not sure how big the enum is on the C++ size. That's why I've put an explicit MarshalAs in the C# code. If it's just a single byte, then use UnmanagedType.U1 instead. I trust you get the idea.

If your C++ function treats its parameter as an in/out parameter then using ref on the C# side is correct. If its actually an out parameter then change the code to be like this:

```
[DllImport("VistaGMMDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int function(out RESOURCE_PARAMETERS parameters);

RESOURCE_PARAMETERS parameters;
int result = function(out parameters);
```

Comment: Hi .. I added the Calling convention.Cdecl. My structure is in C++ DLL, struct RESOURCE_PARAMETERS{
unsigned int uSurfaceHeight;      
unsigned int uSurfaceDepth;       
unsigned int uSurfaceWidth;     
unsigned int    uMSAAHeight;         
unsigned int    uMSAAWidth;          
unsigned int    uArraySize;
unsigned int uNumSamples;   
unsigned int uMaxLod;  
unsigned int uBpp;
unsigned int uprefFlag;
unsigned int uusageFlag;
RESOURCE_TYPE_REC       ResourceType;
int     ResourceFormat;
int iBuildNumber;
} where RESOURCE_TYPE_REC is anEnum

Comment: in c# the structure is  In c#  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]struct ResourceParameters
{public UInt32 uSurfaceHeight;      
public UInt32 uSurfaceDepth;    
public UInt32 uSurfaceWidth;  
public UInt32 uMSAAHeight;         
public UInt32 uMSAAWidth;       
public UInt32 uArraySize;
public UInt32 uNumSamples;   
public UInt32 uMaxLod;             
public UInt32 uBpp;
public UInt32 uprefFlag;
public UInt32 uusageFlag;
public ResourceTypeRec ResourceType;
public Int32 ResourceFormat;  
public Int32 iBuildNumber;
} in this also ResourceTypeRec is an enum

Comment: shall i give the enum structure too??

Answer (score -1):

Another very simple way to call this function is:

```
Create a c++ dll warapper that link your original dll and contains this function

//c++ code

function2(uint param1, uint param2.....)
{
  RefPar refpar;

  refpar.param1=param1

  refpar.param2=param2

  function(&refpar)

}



in this way you have just to import (in C#) the dll wrapper function in this way


[DllImport("wrapperdll.dll", EntryPoint = "function2"]
static extern int function2(Uint32 param1,Uint32 param2....);


that is very simple to call.


Regards
```